# What is the best way to update object array value in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

My React `state`:

```
//...
this.state = {
    mylist: [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "trueorfalse": false
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "trueorfalse": false
        }
    ]
}
//...
```

I am trying to update the `trueorfalse` value based on the `id`

Here is what I did so far but didn't work:

```
var idnum = e.target.id.toString().split("_")[1] //getting the id via an element id (0 or 1 in this case)
var TorF = true
if (type === 1) {
    this.setState({
        mylist: this.state.mylist.map(el => (el.id === idnum ? Object.assign({}, el, { TorF }) : el))
    })
}
```

I really want to make it dynamic so the `trueorfase` will be opposite of what it is now:

```
var idnum = e.target.id.toString().split("_")[1] //getting the id via an element id (0 or 1 in this case)
if (type === 1) {
    this.setState({
        mylist: this.state.mylist.map(el => (el.id === idnum ? Object.assign({}, el, { /* if already true set to false or vice versa */ }) : el))
    })
}
```

How can I update my code to have the dynamicity shown in the second example (if possible), otherwise the first example would do just fine

Comment: You could negate the existing property like `!el.trueorfalse`

Comment: `{ !el.trueorfalse }` didn't work, it instead gave an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code would accomplish your second question.

```
var idnum = e.target.id.toString().split("_")[1]
let newList = Array.from(this.state.mylist) //create new array so we don't modify state directly
if (type === 1) {
    let objToUpdate = newList.find((el) =>  el.id === idnum) // grab first element with matching id
    objToUpdate.trueorfalse = !objToUpdate.trueorfalse
    this.setState( { mylist: newList } )
}
```

Comment: Should the last list be `mylist: objToUpdate`?

Comment: @Si8 no, `objToUpdate` is just a single element from `updatedList`

Comment: You beat me to fixing the `setState` method.

Comment: Btw this fixed my issue, so much simpler than I imagined! Thanks.

Comment: @Michael You didn't update `newList` with the updated object.

Comment: @JossClassey Because I changed `objToUpdate`, `newList` is also changed. It's like the following code: `a = ls[3]; a.x = 5` <- You just changed the third element of `ls`.

Comment: Ahh, I thought `find()` would return a new object, but no it returns a reference to the original array. Very interesting.

Comment: I was a little confused too but then realized that it's not s new object but a reference to the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `map`:

[image: Edit withered-field-889f8]

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mylist: [
        {
          id: 0,
          trueorfalse: false
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          trueorfalse: true
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  toggleBoolean = () => {
    const ID = Number(this.state.selectedID);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      mylist: prevState.mylist.map(item => {
        if (item.id === ID) {
          return { ...item, trueorfalse: !item.trueorfalse };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      })
    }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>{`State values: ${JSON.stringify(this.state.mylist)}`}</p>
        <button onClick={this.toggleBoolean}>Change true/false values</button>
        <label>Insert ID:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          onChange={event => this.setState({ selectedID: event.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh this also works. Which would be more efficient to use, or it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Si8 I think the performance would be pretty similar because both copy/create a new array and iterate over every element of the existing array. Either way though I think choosing based on efficiency at this point would be micro-optimizing; just pick which way makes more sense in your head.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the clarification.